# Requests-HTML - Page rendering of Java script not working

Tags: javascript, rendering, python-requests-html

I'm trying to load the price history of Nestle through Requests-HTML.
The script I'm using is:

```
import asyncio
import requests            
import requests_html

# Jupyter Notebooks related imports
import nest_asyncio        
nest_asyncio.apply()
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
test_url= 'https://www.finanzen.ch/kurse/historisch/nestle/swx/1.1.2022_3.7.2022'
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
rq = await asession.get(test_url)
rq.html.arender()
with open(Path ('HTML_Req_rendered.html'), 'wb') as f:
    test_txt= f.write(rq.html.raw_html)
```

The file `HTML_Req_rendered.html` [GoogleDriveLink](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JWSxtM6RVR5I1VgIH-K6ZxQ66e1pbWKz/view?usp=sharing) is generated correctly but does not contain the price history loaded by javaScript.
Please see the [link top webpage](https://www.finanzen.ch/kurse/historisch/nestle/swx/1.1.2022_3.7.2022).

Can anyone help?
What am I doing wrong?
How can I get a rendered HTML?

Any help is kindly appreciate. Thx.
Stefano

Comment: You should tag this question as `python`, not `javascript`. You have to use selenium or anything that will load the webpage in the browser and then scrap the data.

Comment: According to the documentation, requests-HTML is supposed to render the page as well. Isn't it? Selenium is a lot more complicated. Does anyone know how to render the price history with requests-HTML?